# How to uploading test result in HP ALM

Tags: java, selenium, alm

i want to run my test script written in Java+Selenium+TestNG in HP ALM. I created Vapi-XP test and batch file which run my test. But if test failed it will report a pass. How to uploading test result?

```
mycommand = "C:\PSelenium\RunVapi.bat"
TDOutput.Print "Starting " & mycommand
result=run(mycommand,0,true)
TDOutput.Print "Test ended with " & result
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [Agiletestware Bumblebee](https://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee) integration platform which can help you to automate exporting results of Java+Selenium+TestNG tests into HP ALM. Check out [this](https://www.agiletestware.com/docs/bumblebee-docs/en/latest/qa-frameworks/selenium-webdriver/) and [this](https://www.agiletestware.com/docs/bumblebee-docs/en/latest/ci-integration/jenkins/#-export-tests-results) also.

Disclaimer: I'm developer of Bumblebee

Comment: Mmm.. it is good. but what if I do not have internet in my work PC??

Comment: I think this is more a question to your network administrator to allow download and use bumblebee installer

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 Global Objects in the scope of a VAPI-XP Test: CurrentRun, CurrentTest. They correspond to the [Run and Test interfaces](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.55/api_refs/ota/webframe.html#topic8727.html) respectively. Setting the Status property on Both Objects should be the way.